# Restrict usage of S3 pre-signed URL to a particular account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have a S3 bucket. I wish to provide a pre-signed URL to another account (lets  say Account A) to upload data into it.  Is there a way I can ensure only Account A is allowed to upload using the pre-signed URL?
I want to avoid scenario where another (lets say Account B) uses the pre-signed URL (meant for Account A) to upload data.

Answer (score 0):

pre-signed URL is not checking account at all. As long as creator of pre-signed URL has the permissions to upload, anybody can use this URL to update. Pretty much what anonymous FTP used to allow, but in a time-limited way. That's why you would create URL that only lasts for few minutes to give your customer an opportunity to upload the file.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Answer (score 0):

Presigned URL is getting signed using the provided headers at its creation time. When using pre-signed URL with `HTTP request` there is a validation process between the request headers and the pre-signed URL signature, if there is a mismatch,it throws a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error. So by generating the pre-signed URL with specific `hash` header, and passing it only to Account A, each request without this `hash` header will get rejected.
You can check out this post to do so [How to send content md5 header in the presigned url request of node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63401051/how-to-send-content-md5-header-in-the-presigned-url-request-of-node-js)