# How to send content md5 header in the presigned url request of node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, md5, pre-signed-url

I want to check the integrity of the object uploaded to S3.So I want to include the md5 header so whenever soomeone uses that url they should upload only the valid content.
FYI: I would get the md5 content from the UI to my service.

```
const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
      Key: id,
      Expires: 300,
      Metadata: metadata,
    };

this.s3ClientAccelerate.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add ContentMD5 like this.

```
const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: id, Expires: 300, Metadata: metadata,ContentMD5: md5, };
```

And make sure you pass Content-MD5 in headers of client.

Answer (score 0):

`signedUrl`, as we can understand from its name, signs the URL using its required headers and the user's custom headers. If you want from the signed URL to validate the request, you just need to attach the relevant hash at the `signedUrl` creation, if the signature of the request won't match the signature of the `signedUrl` that was created, it will respond with a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error.

```
const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
      Key: id,
      Expires: 300,
      Metadata: metadata,
      MD5: uiMD5
    };

this.s3ClientAccelerate.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to create base64 md5 hash.

```
const md5Hash = hash.update(data, 'utf-8').digest();
const buffer = Buffer.from(md5Hash);
const base64 = buffer.toString('base64');
console.log('MD5 base64:', base64);
```

For a pre-signed URL, Amazon S3 uses a base64 hash, while ETag is in hexadecimal hash.